# Trying to make a 2D array of lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm trying to write a model containing digital organisms. Within the model i'd liek the environment to be a fixed 2-d array, but each cell needs to contain a list of the organisms in it. I tried using a jagged array, but as the number of occupied elements varies quite a bit throughout the programm run, i need to use something more flexible than an array. I've tried making a 2-D array of the type list, but im getting errors with it.

```
    List<Creature>[,] theWorld;


    public Environment()
    { 
        List<Creature>[,] theWorld = new List<Creature>[100,100];
    }

    public void addCreature(Creature c)
    {
       for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
            {
                theWorld[x, y].Add (c);

            } } }
```

this is the segment where i'm trying to declare the array at the beginning, as a type that holds lists (of the organisms), and later i try to add a creature (c) to each of the lists in each element of the array.

when i run it i get the following error message-

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HGT_sim_2.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

and the line "World[x, y].Add (c);" is highlighted.

If anyone can tell me what i'm doing wrong, and even better, a way around the problem, it'd be amazing.
thank you ain advance!

Comment: Usually y comes first then x when mapping a 2d array, but I guess the order is subjective. Doing it y then x will give an accurate visual output though from the top left corner.

Answer (score 8):

All your array contains initially is a lot of nulls. You need to actually create the lists...

```
for(int x = 0 ; x < 100 ; x++)
    for(int y = 0 ; y < 100 ; y++)
        theWorld[x,y] = new List<Creature>();
```

Personally, though, I expect this will be a costly way to do things...

It depends in part on whether the data is "sparse" - i.e. are most of the cells usually taken? A simple (but possibly more efficient) approach, for example, would be to use something like multi-map; i.e.

```
Point pt = new Point(x,y);
theWorld.Add(pt, someCreature);
```

where `theWorld` could be something like `EditableLookup<Point, Creature>` (using `EditableLookup<,>` from "[MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/)"). That way, you can still query it by co-ordinate, and have multiple creatures *on* a coordinate, but you don't have to allocate space for every cell. And because it functions as a dictionary it is still fast. Not *as* fast as a flat array, but it will scale to bigger (sparse) grids... of course, if the grid has creatures on every cell it could be *more* expensive! Hence the need to understand your data.

Comment: PowerCollections contains a MultiDictionary<K,T> which will help

Comment: Indeed. If you haven't written your own multi-map at some point you haven't been trying ;-p

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize each member of your array, e.g.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        {
            theWorld[x, y] = new List<Creature>();

        } }
```

Comment: PS ... do that BEFORE the code you posted that adds to the list ;-)

Comment: Just found use of this! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fix:

```
List<Creature>[,] theWorld;


public Environment()
{ 
    theWorld = new List<Creature>[100,100]; // Remove the type, you were creating a new list and throwing it away...

    for(int x = 0 ; x < 100 ; x++)
       for(int y = 0 ; y < 100 ; y++)
          theWorld[x,y] = new List<Creature>();    
}

public void addCreature(Creature c)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        {
            theWorld[x, y].Add (c);

        } } }
```

Comment: Added a comment to tell you, in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the array object to hold your lists, but you haven't created the list itself. You will need to do the following in your constructor:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) 
    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        theWorld[x,y] = new List<Creature>();
```

Another problem: you were also defining `theWorld` as a local variable in your constructor, which means your `theWorld` field on `Environment` was never initialized, either.

However, 10,000 `List`s may be overkill for what you really need. If your Environment really needs a `Creature` at every point, and some Creatures may move to other points (where there is more than one at a point, then it may make more sense to use a `Dictionary<Point, IList<Creature>>` as your model versus 10,000 lists.

```
public void Add(Creature c, Point at)
{
    IList<Creature> list;
    if (!theWorld.TryGetValue(at)) {
        list = theWorld[at] = new List<Creature>();
    }
    list.Add(c);
}
```

You can then implement `Move` and `Remove` methods similarly. Also, note that you are adding the *same* Creature to every point, which (may) mean that there's one Creature at all points in your Environment. You will probably want to create a `new Creature()` for every point, if that's what you are actually modeling.

Comment: Partially true, but it wouldn't work without fixing the code in the constructor

Comment: Edited to include that and another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
List<Creature>[,] theWorld = new List<Creature>[100,100];
```

You're creating an array of `List<Creature>` references, but they are all empty (pointing to null, not a valid List).  You need to initialize each individual element:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
       theWorld[i,j] = new List<Creature>();
    }
}
```

Once you've done that, you'll be able to call .Add on the individual members.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it almost correct. Your variable is a 2D array of `List<Creature>`. Now, `List<Creature>` is a reference type, so the array is initialized to contain `null`'s in all its members. Thus you get the `NullReferenceException`. The line

```
theWorld[x, y].Add (c);
```

is basically equivalent to

```
null.Add (c);
```

All you need to do is to initialize all the members to contain instances of `List<Creature>`. The best way to do this would be in the constructor. Just rewrite it like this:

```
public Environment()
{ 
    theWorld = new List<Creature>[100,100];
    for(int x = 0 ; x < 100 ; x++)
        for(int y = 0 ; y < 100 ; y++)
            theWorld[x,y] = new List<Creature>();
}
```

Now all the operations will work as expected.

Also note, that in your example you are creating a local variable with the same name as the class member. This way you don't initialize the class member at all - it stays null.